# If PHP always copies objects by reference, what happens if an object created in a method is assigned to a member variable?

Tags: php

I'm confused what would happen in this situation:

```
public function foo() {
    $obj = new \stdClass();
    $obj->bar = 'foobar';

    $this->obj = $obj;
}
```

If `$obj` is copied by reference, then when `foo()` returns, won't `$obj` be deleted and thus `$this->obj` point to an object that no longer exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the method this is what it looks like:

```
$obj ---------.
               >-- [OBJECT]
$this->obj --´
```

When the method returns the `$obj` variable is destroyed, and the `$this->obj` variable will still point to the object:

```
$this->obj ------> [OBJECT]
```

The `[OBJECT]` value will only disappear (or be garbage collected) once all references to it have been removed.